# Reg EXP Vimeo URL

Tags: regex, expression, vimeo

Can anybody help with an reg exp to only return the :id of this url

http://vimeo.com/2857713

That is : "2857713" i want returned

thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
\/\d+$
```

[Tested against your link](http://rubular.com/r/q6yhAwcuu4)